# angularjs directive - element.html() breaks transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Reference plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r6JZCyavk1IqQgoxLq0Q?p=preview)

If I call `element.html()` in my link function, the transcluded elements no longer compile.  That really says it all, and the plunker will demonstrate, but here's the code:

Directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  var compile, config, link;

  link = function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.html();
  };

  compile = function() {
    return link;
  };

  config = {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    compile: compile,
    scope: {}
  };

  return config;
});
```

Html:

In the following, the output is just the uncompiled `{{foo}}`

```
  <div my-directive>
    {{foo}}
  </div>
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something fundamental?

N.B. This is *not* a problem if `element.html()` is called in the `compile` function.

Angular v1.0.6, jQuery v1.9.1

Comment: you're not supposed to return the link function from the compile function, are you ?

Comment: you can - that's one of about 100 ways to write a directive.  I usually use the most verbose option :)

Comment: it seems to work using the `link: ->` option instead tho

Comment: If I remove jQuery it works.  Also, your plunker is using Angular 1.0.5 (using 1.0.6 with jQuery doesn't work either though).

Comment: Checking the jQuery source, it seems that `.html()` does a replace on the content even when just using it as a getter.  That may have a lot to do with the issue, but I'm not sure in what way.

Comment: Raised an issue for this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2830

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code: Here is the

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EpZLV/1/)

```
 <div my-directive>
   {{foo}}
 </div>
```

Resolves to:

```
<div my-directive>
 test    
</div>
```